Minimizing and Maximizing Null Space during training a language model
I am trying various training objectives for a proof-of-concept language model experiment. I want to explore how minimizing and maximizing the null space during training will affect downstream task performance. I am a beginner, however, and I don't know where to start with implementing this objective. Any help would be appreciated. I am using huggingface models, tokenizers, and trainer. And I am using PyTorch as the deep learning framework. Thanks !
Was looking to get some feedback from real people before trying my luck with an LLM.
